# Facebook UI - share larger image

Tags: javascript, image, facebook-ui

We're launching a web application (html/js/css, all browsers) where a user can build their own custom image as part of the experience. We generate it server side and return it to the page. It's stored in our file system in a publicly accessible location.

I can successfully use FB UI to open the share dialog, allowing the user to share caption/link and a thumbnail of the image they've generated.

If you paste a link directly to a media (img/vid) on facebook itself, it shows the image preview below the post, rather than the thumbnail that FB UI shows. We'd like to mimic the large preview behavior.

Is there a way to get the larger image via FB UI?

I've tried passing in the direct link to the image file (jpg) as each parameter in the [feed and share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) function, and it always just shows it in the thumbnail (or no image, if I remove the picture parameter.)

Has anyone done this successfully, or have any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to share a link, or publish a photo?

Comment: @CBroe share a link with a large preview (like posting a link to a photo on Facebook itself) would be preferable. Is there an "easy" dialog for publishing a photo? I'd be willing to consider that as well.

Comment: For a link thumbnail you can only follow FB guidelines on picture size and aspect ratio; you can not “force” in which format it will be displayed, FB decides that (although in the future they will most likely chose the bigger display wherever possible). Uploading a photo is not possible via dialog, that has to happen via API.